# javascript browse file and show content in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Can any one help me to get the text to iframe using input method, rather than using SRC.
i am using this to read text and use it in IE8 as alternative to fileReader method so that i can use the data in the text file for my requirement
the code lines are.

```
<input type="file" name="fileread" />
<iframe id='iframe1' name='iframe1' src='fileread'> </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading files in javascript is not as easy as it sounds like. I suggest that first you check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader, there's a documentation. I found an great article from the net related to your question: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=9oig0UB93RL.

Hope you will find something.

Comment: Thank you.. i will go through it

Comment: Actually fileReader works perfect in mozilla. I have tested it already. But I am using IE8 which doesn't support fileReader() method. So searching for alternative.

Comment: Umm.. i guess then you have to use ajax and server side scripting.. or at least, your question goes way harder to achive.